# How to remove EntranceThemeTransition from object or container in Windows 8 Store Apps?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How do I remove the default [EntranceThemeTransition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.entrancethemetransition) in XAML that seems (by default) to be added to all controls in Windows 8 Store Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using one of the project/item templates (Split App, Grid App, etc.), you'll see a StandardStyles.xaml in the Common directory of your solution.  It includes the following markup at the very end. You can remove it/modify it there.

```
<Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```