# How to remove EntranceThemeTransition from a single object in a Windows 8 App?

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

It seems like every object that has been added to a page in a Windows 8 App gets this "slide from right to left"-entrance-transition which begins whenever someone navigates to the page.

Is there a possibility to remove single objects from this transition?

Neither

```
<Object.Transitions>
      <TransitionCollection />
</Object.Transitions>
```

nor [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820097/how-to-remove-entrancethemetransition-from-object-or-container-in-windows-8-stor) helped...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There's no way to exempt a given object from the transitions applied by it's parents. The only thing I can suggest is to structure your xaml in such a way that the transition isn't applied. By this I mean having this special item in a panel that has no children transitions while the rest of the page is in a panel with a child transition. Depending on where this item is it could be very easy or difficult as hell.

Answer (score 0):

As [Nigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90457/nigel-sampson) suggested, the only solution I have found has been to change the page structure and put the elements out of the grid that has the animations:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection/>
            <!-- Ensure no transitions in background -->
        </Grid.Transitions>

        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Margin="50">This item is not animated</TextBlock>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <!-- add transitions here -->
                    <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="1500" FromHorizontalOffset="1500"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="50,100" FontSize="50">This item is animated</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Margin="50,150">Another not animated item</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```